# Reactive form validation from ts

Tags: angular

I am trying to centralized validation message with type.
Suppose form is raw or untouched i.e prestine when user submit the form without touching the field i want to show only name is required and email is required messsage only

I have added submitted boolean to figure out but ngIf will always evaluate to false

```
validationCondition(type: string, controlName: string): boolean {
     return this.myForm.get(`${controlName}`).hasError(`${type}`) &&(this.myForm.get(`${controlName}`).touched || this.myForm.get(`${controlName}`).dirty);
  }
```

Here we can do something but i m not getting the idea what should i put in order to work with submit too

Link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tiey4d

I would like to see name is required and email is required when user is submitting the form without touching any field. Also i would like to see validation message while typing in field or leaving from field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just in onSubmit

```
 onSubmit() { 
    if (!this.myForm.valid) //if not valid
    {
       this.submitted = true  // because you put the condition "if submitted"
       this.myForm.markAllAsTouched() //mark all the controls as touched
    }else
    {
       console.log(this.myForm.value)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if form has errors with this boolean in root obj.

```
this.myForm.invalid
```

Comment: With that when you type validation will not work if i put invalid along with touched, Then it is showing all validation message. Thank you for your response.